# GeoServer Exception When Publishing A Layer Based On A Geopackage Store

Tags: geoserver, geopackage

I exported a map from MapTiler to a GeoPackage, and created a store in GeoServer for it. When I tried publishing the layer based on that store, I got the following exception:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@7abe659c on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:435)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$9.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:324)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.getImageLayout(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:1231)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.getImageLayout(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:483)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.getImageLayout(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getCoverageSampleDimensions(CatalogBuilder.java:1159)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverageInternal(CatalogBuilder.java:1023)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:944)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:893)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:422)
    ... 113 more
```

I have no experience with this, but according to some other similar posts, this might be a compatibility issue? If so, is there a way to rectify that? If not, what steps can be taken to address this issue?

**Update:** I realize now that this probably was because I needed to install the GeoPackage community extension as detailed here (https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.14.x/doc/en/user/community/geopkg/installing.html). I had incorrectly assumed that because the option was available in the store list, that it was already installed.

However, after installing the community package, I am still getting the above exception.

**Update 2:** The output from gdalinfo (GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16) is as follows:

```
$ gdalinfo 1870-3.gpkg 
ERROR 1: bad application_id on '1870-3.gpkg'
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '1870-3.gpkg'.
```

Opening the file with a SQLite browser, I was able to find the application_id in main options: 1196444487. Not sure if this is pertinent: I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 (will be upgrading to 18.04 in the near future).

**Update 3:** after upgrading to GDAL 2.x, GDALINFO provided the following output: (output removed in favor of update 4)

**Update 4:** After updating to GDAL 2.2.x, the output of `gdalinfo` is the following: (output removed in favor of update 5)

**Update 5:** After updating to GDAL 2.3.2 and fixing the user_version field, the above error still remains and the output is of `gdalinfo` is the following:

```
GNM: GNMRegisterAllInternal
GNM: RegisterGNMFile
GNM: RegisterGNMdatabase
GPKG: GeoPackage v1.2.0
GDAL: GDALOpen(1870-3.gpkg, this=0x6ef5e0) succeeds as GPKG.
Driver: GPKG/GeoPackage
Files: 1870-3.gpkg
Size is 13691, 19104
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Google Maps Global Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
Origin = (-7953558.976533000357449,5139746.788745000027120)
Pixel Size = (0.597164283477939,-0.597164283477939)
Metadata:
  DESCRIPTION=MapTiler Desktop Plus 10.0-788fb78a7d
  IDENTIFIER=package_tiles
  ZOOM_LEVEL=18
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-7953558.977, 5139746.789) ( 71d26'52.93"W, 41d51'29.15"N)
Lower Left  (-7953558.977, 5128338.562) ( 71d26'52.93"W, 41d46'54.20"N)
Upper Right (-7945383.200, 5139746.789) ( 71d22'28.53"W, 41d51'29.15"N)
Lower Right (-7945383.200, 5128338.562) ( 71d22'28.53"W, 41d46'54.20"N)
Center      (-7949471.088, 5134042.676) ( 71d24'40.73"W, 41d49'11.72"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 6846x9552, 3423x4776, 1711x2388, 856x1194, 428x597, 214x299, 107x149
GDAL: GDALClose(1870-3.gpkg, this=0x6ef5e0)
```

**UPDATE** I am still experiencing this issue when trying to import GeoPackages in GeoServer 2.15.0. (The MBTiles plugin did not work and appears to be abandoned.)

Comment: It looks like GeoServer doesn't like your image layout, can you run gdalinfo on the geopackage and add that to the question

Comment: Thanks, Ian -- I'm just learning the ropes and getting familiar with all the commands to manipulate geo files. I have added the info above in update 2.

Comment: It looks like a broken geopackage

Comment: I just updated GDAL to more recent version and ran again. It seems to see all the GIS information, but has a problem with the application_id value. From searching on the internet, this seems to be the correct value for geopackages, is it not?

Comment: I saw that GeoServer also has a MBTiles plugin, so I'm using that for now, until I can get GeoPackages to work. I confirmed that it does work with the export from MapTiler Desktop. :)

Comment: That application ID is "GPKG", which is only valid for GPKG 1.2 (or later). Most earlier tools only support earlier versions, which explains the error. You need at least GDAL 2.2 to get GPKG 1.2 support.

Comment: Thanks @BradHards, I went ahead and updated GDAL to version 2.2.3, and updated the `gdalinfo` output.

Comment: That GeoPackage is not spec conformant. It doesn't meet some of the "shall" in Requirement 2 (http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/#_sqlite_container): `A GeoPackage SHALL contain an appropriate value in "user_version" field of the SQLite database header to indicate its version. The value SHALL be in integer with a major version, two-digit minor version, and two-digit bug-fix. For GeoPackage Version 1.2 this value is 0x000027D8 (the hexadecimal value for 10200).`

Comment: Thanks, @BradHards. I will try editing the package and fixing user_version field and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue remains even after fixing the user_version value. I suspect this might not be related to the format of the geopackage file itself, but perhaps something else? I am running this on a 3-CPU, 1GB RAM, Ubuntu 18.04 VPS on DigitalOcean.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding: I was commenting on the GeoPackage, not trying to answer the question. I think the problem is that GeoServer doesn't support GeoPackage 1.2.